# elasticsearch nested aggregate based on attribute and get custom value based on a formula in every bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have dataset of Event actions:

```
 {"person" : "person1", "event" : "e1", "action" : "like"}
 {"person" : "person2", "event" : "e1", "action" : "dislike"}
 {"person" : "person1", "event" : "e1", "action" : "share"}
 {"person" : "person1", "event" : "e1", "action" : "rating"}
 {"person" : "person1", "event" : "e2", "action" : "rating"}
```

Can I aggregate based on the event and then on the bucket, based on weighted metrics on the actions get a single custom value from the bucket?

I have already done nested aggregation:

```
{
 "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "all_events": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "overall_ratings": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "action.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

}

So I get the result:

- e1 -> like - 10, dislike: 4, share: 8
- e2 -> like - 30, dislike: 0, share: 2

But I want to apply some formula to get

- e1 -> (like*5) + (dislike* -3) + (share*2) = (10*5)+(4*-3)+(8*2) =
  50-12+16= 54

I want:

- e1 -> 54
- e2 -> 154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can build quite complicated formulas with aggregations. Use [Scripted Metric aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation).

In your example - with the data you provied - the result should be:

```
e1 -> (1*5) + (1*-3) + (1*2) = 5 - 3 + 2 = 4
e2 -> 0
```

The aggregating query would have to be:

```
{
 "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "all_events": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "overall_ratings": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "params._agg.transactions = [];",
            "map_script": "if (doc.action.value == 'like') params._agg.transactions.add(5); if (doc.action.value == 'dislike') params._agg.transactions.add(-3); if (doc.action.value == 'share') params._agg.transactions.add(2);",
            "combine_script" : "int total = 0; for (t in params._agg.transactions) { total += t; } return total;",
            "reduce_script" : "int total = 0; for (a in params._aggs) { total += a; } return total;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this query gave me following result:

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 5,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "all_events": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "e1",
                    "doc_count": 4,
                    "overall_ratings": {
                        "value": 4
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "e2",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "overall_ratings": {
                        "value": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**One importanat thing** - it may be necessary to have `action` field set in the mapping with **`"fielddata": true`**:

```
"action": {
    "type": "text",
    ...,
    "fielddata": true
}
```

Otherwise you'll get an exception with *"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default...."*